# joining 2 tables with non unique IDs for merge

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to migrate data from another table to mine.  However, the ID i have to use to join them is not unique (~10% of the IDs from either tables are duplicated, they are not primary keys).

eg. table A has IDs `(1, 1, 2, 3)` and table B has values `(1, 2, 2, 3, 4)` how can I join them so they either omit duplicates or take ANY value from the other table as the correct link?

My goal is to return a view where there are no duplicate rows at all in the ID column I am joining on.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `row_number()` for the query:

```
select a.*, b.*
from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from tablea a
     ) a join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as seqnum
      from tableb b
     ) b
     on a.id = b.id and a.seqnum = 1 and b.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: ORA-01555 snapshot too old.  what is this?

Comment: This isn't directly related to the query.  You can find more information about the problem online, such as here:  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:1441804355350.